# Displaying text stream in swing

Tags: java, swing, text

So I have a socket connected and constantly reading from a server. I have no problem printing lines to the terminal as they arrive, but I'm struggling with Swing. I want to add each line to the display as it comes in, with certain pre-defined words highlighted. I looked at JEditPane, and the only way I could see would be `setText(getText()+newText)`, which I looked at and thought it looked very wrong. I had a look at the Document classes, and none of them seems to have an obvious `append` method. Am I missing something obvious, or is there an easy way to do this with another component?

Comment: What is it doing? Why is it not what you want? Can we see the code you are using to test this?

Comment: when I said looked wrong, I mean the code looks weird, like there should be a better way :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to address this would be to create a `JTextPane` with a `DocumentListener` that will do your necessary hightlight.
Create your text as you get from server and call `insertString` on the text pane's document. The `insertString` would work as append.

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#insertString%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet%29) out.

Comment: I knew there was an obvious thing I'd missed. Hadn't seen `insertString`. D'oh!